# What are the fourier coefficients of the $ 2 \pi $ periodic function $f(x) = x$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a $ 2 \pi $ periodic function, that is even, and: $ \forall x \in [0, \pi]: f(x) = x $

> What are the Fourier coefficient.

---

Since the function is pair, we will have: $b_n = 0$ and:

$ a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x dx = 0 $

$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x \cos(nx) dx = \frac{1}{\pi n^2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx) dx = 0$

Using integration by parts, I find $ 0 $, which is absurd since the function is pair. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: If function is even (pair), then for $x<0$ you should use $f(x)=-x$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu My mistake, the function is even: $ f(- x) = x $

Comment: @coudy The function is even, on the interval $(- \pi, 0)$, we have: $f(-x) = f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $f(x)=-x$ if $x\in (-\pi, 0]$, then your coefficient is given by

$$
$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} x \cos(nx) dx + \int_{-\pi}^{0} -x \cos(nx) dx  \neq 0.
$$
You just forgot the minus sign for negative values of $x$.

Comment: The function is even, for $x \in ( -\pi, 0): f(x) = f(-x) = x$

Comment: So for negative $x$, you have $f(x) = -x \geq 0$.

Comment: I do not know if I am mistaken, but if we have an even function, we will have: $ f( -x ) = f(x) = x $, the output would be the same whether the input is negative or positive.

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: Your function $f$ is actually the absolute value on $(-\pi,\pi)$ : $f(x) = |x|$. Indeed, the absolute value is even and coincides with $x$ for $x>0$. Now $|x| = -x$ if $x$ is negative.